# Exported PDF file is not scaled as per setting

Tags: excel

My Excel file is in A4 paper size but the export PDF is in Letter paper size.  [Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFb6.png) and the
[Exported PDF using MS Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTups.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this might be due to application setting. In MS Excel, File->Option->Advanced-> disable Scale to A4 or 8.5 * 11 option. This might resolve your issue.

[Setting screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptYSP.png)